# My code wont print out the data within my database

Tags: java, sql, database

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package ai_assignment;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author ADAM KENYON
 */
public class AI_Assignment {
    String connectString = "D:\\Users\\ADAM KENYON\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\AI_Assignment\\Database\\AI_assignment";
    private static Object ex;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.text.ParseException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        // TODO code application logic here
       AI_Assignment assignment = new AI_Assignment(); assignment.database();

    }

    public void database() throws ParseException {
        try {
            Connection con;
            Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:" + connectString, // filenames
                    "", // username
                    "");  // password
            try (Statement statement = con.createStatement()) {
                ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TEST");
                while (rs.next()) {
                    int ID = rs.getInt("ID");
                    System.out.print(ID);
                }
                 statement.close();
                  con.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException SQLException) {
            Logger.getLogger(AI_Assignment.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, SQLException);
        }
    }
}
```

So far this is what I have and it all compiles but none of the data gets printed out into the output. Any help?

I was following an online tutorial and I guess I did something wrong but I dont know. My guess is that the connectString variable is wrong gonna mess with that while I wait for responses.

EDIT: THe code is now up to date and this is the error the gets thrown
"Nov 25, 2015 5:35:13 AM ai_assignment.AI_Assignment database
SEVERE: null

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jdbcDriver"

Comment: why do you need `"` and backslash in your query ?

Comment: Well I was as I said following an online tutorial and thats how they did it so I followed it :(

Comment: So please try removing these. Because its a jdbc query string, does not require it. And also check if your column names are correct in terms of case also. And last, does any such table exists with these fields and data for them. They are just the debugging stages.

Comment: Removing them throws errors. and the tables and data is all there and correct as far as I can tell

Comment: what errors does it throw?

Comment: You have mentioned "AI_assignment"TEST to be your table name. Is this what you want ? Have you also tried printing your query. And I apologise for   one wrong thing I mentioned in my previous comment. Actually case doesn't matter with column and table names in jdbc query.

Comment: I am at uni right now so I will give errors it throws when I get home. As for the table name yeah that is correct. I can try printing my query when I get home too

Comment: I updated the code and a new error message

Comment: Do you have have the hsqldb jar on your build path?

Comment: yeah I do, I think xD

Answer (score 0):

Based on the most recent exception listed in the question you are having problems loading the JDBC driver.  Checking [hsqldb's documentation](http://hsqldb.org/doc/src/org/hsqldb/jdbc/JDBCDriver.html) you should replace `Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");` with `Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver");`

Comment: I think I might have the jar put in wrong to be honest but I dont know how to do that correctly